# Querying custom field through REST API in VersionOne

Tags: versionone

Query:

I have a custom field named Custom_ProductOwner and I am trying the below query.

/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/Story?sel=Custom_ProductOwner

I get this error. How do I query custom fields using REST API?

{"Error":{"Exception":[{"Message":"Unknown token: Custom_ProductOwner","class":"VersionOne.MetaException"},{"Message":"(1) Unknown AttributeDefinition: Story.Custom_ProductOwner\n(2) Unknown token: Custom_ProductOwner","class":"VersionOne.MultipleException"}],"Message":"Invalid SEL parameter","href":"/Example/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/Story?Custom_ProductOwner&where=Scope='Scope:251757'"}}

Thank you
Bhushan

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct form of the [rest-1.v1](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Endpoints/rest-1.v1%2F%2FData) query but maybe the attribute name is not exactly what you expect. The name is case sensitive.

To query the metadata, you can use the [meta.v1](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Endpoints/meta.v1) endpoint.

```
<System Base URI>/meta.v1/Story?xsl=api.xsl
```